# match operator in function argument in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I was going through elixir project code base and i encounter the following
please help me out what is here the matching operation is doing in function argument??

```rb
{ result, errors } = validate(schema, data, "", data)
```

```rb
def validate(root = %{ custom: validator }, data, path, full_data) when is_function(validator) do
  { result, errors } = if Map.has_key?(root, :type), do: validate( Map.drop(root, [:custom]) , data, path ), else: { data, [] }
  case validator.(full_data, result, path) do
    { :ok, value } -> { value, errors }
    { :error, error } -> { result, errors ++ [ %{ param: path, code: :validation_error, message: error  } ]  }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very idiomatic code that serves several purposes:

1. It ensures that the `root` parameter is a map that contains `custom` key (it might or might not contain other keys too, but we don't care about them)
2. If so, it destructures it in place and binds `custom`'s value to the `validator`
3. It then additionally ensures (using a guard) that `validator` is a function

You can achieve the same via explicit checks within a function body, but this would be more verbose, probably less efficient, and for sure less idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

[As the other answer is like a fish, I'd like to contribute a bit and show you how to fish.](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/08/28/fish/). You can use this technique to quickly try out all the wacky edge cases you're not sure about and see the behavior.

You can fire up `iex` and type something like this:

```
defmodule Foo do                                     
   def validate(root = %{custom: validator}) do         
     IO.puts(inspect(root))                               
     IO.puts(inspect(validator))
   end
end
```

Then go crazy and try it out:

```
> Foo.validate(%{custom: "custom-value", other: "yes"})
%{custom: "custom-value", other: "yes"}
"custom-value"

> Foo.validate(%{other: "yes"})
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Foo.validate/1    
    
    The following arguments were given to Foo.validate/1:
    
        # 1
        %{other: "yes"}
    
    iex:5: Foo.validate/1
```

`inspect/1` returns a string representation of a structure, and `IO.puts/1` prints it in the STDOUT.